# Salesforce Apex How to write SOQL outside of for loop

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am working on a Trigger that uses many SOQL statements. I have tried following this guide http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops and it doesn't work for me because IDs in Salesforce are not the exact same as the id's that come up for every item. Here's what I mean:

(Btw this is a child record calling a parent and so the parent child thing doesn't work for me)

```
list<opportunity> listOpportunity = [select id
                                     From opportunity
                                     Where id IN : *Trigger.oldmap.keyset()];*

for(Opportunity opportunity : listOpportunity)
{
     //Do Code here.

}
```

All I want is for this list to be populated with the correct opportunity(s) being triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do not need a SOQL query here, you can just use the following snippets

```apex
// for iterate trough new opportunities
for (Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new) {
     // do something with new Opps
}
```

```apex
 // for iterate trough old opportunities
 for (Opportunity oldOpp: Trigger.oldMap.values()) { 
     // read old values on update trigger
 }
```

also you can combine it

```apex
 // for iterate trough old opportunities

for (Opportunity newOpp: Trigger.new) {
    if (newOpp.field1 != Trigger.oldMap.get(newOpp.Id).field1) {
        // do something for changed field
    }
}
```

==========================================================================

**UPDATE**

@user1991372

I hope this update will be helpful, here is the example of common approach for solving such issue with SOQL in a loop

//------------------ Trigger

```apex
Map<Id, List<Account>> accountsByOpp = new Map<Id, List<Account>>();
 List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Oppty
                                 ,name 
                           FROM account 
                           WHERE oppty IN Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
accountsByOpp = splitListByKey(accounts, 'oppty');

for (Opportunity opp: Trigger.old) {
    List<Account> accs = accountsByOpp.get(opp.Id);
    if (accs != null) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

//------------------- Utility apex

```apex
class CommonException extends Exception {}

public static Map<Id, List<sObject>> splitListByKey(List<sObject> sourceList, String key) {
    if (sourceList == null) {
        throw new CommonException('ERROR: splitListByKey(sourceList, key) got incorrect first parameter.');
    }
    if (key == null || key == '') {
        throw new CommonException('ERROR: splitListByKey(sourceList, key) got incorrect second parameter.');
    }
    Map<Id,List<sObject>> result = new Map<Id,List<sObject>>();
    List<sObject> tmpObjs;
    for (sObject obj: sourceList) {
        tmpObjs = new List<sObject>();
        if (obj.get(key) != null && result.containsKey((Id)obj.get(key))) {
            tmpObjs = result.get((Id)obj.get(key));
            tmpObjs.add(obj);
            result.put((Id)obj.get(key), tmpObjs);
        } else if (obj.get(key) != null) {
            tmpObjs.add(obj);
            result.put((Id)obj.get(key), tmpObjs);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: So maybe I didn't explain very well. I can't use this because I am trying to write SOQL inside the for loop, and I can't write SOQL outside the For loop if I do it this way. Does that make sense? Btw, Pavel you have answered my questions before, I really appreciate how often you have helped me.

Comment: @user1991372 what is the SOQL which you're trying to use into the loop? As I said, the SOQL which is presented in your post is useless, because we already have this list as `Trigger.new` which equals to `[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: Trigger.oldMap.keySet()]` as well as equals to `[SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet()]` and also it's equals to `Trigger.newMap.values()`. Maybe I somewhere got you wrong, please post a whole your code in this case.

Comment: So I want to run a query in the for loop to work with the data, like this:  for(Opportunity Oppty : trigger.old)                                 { account a = [select Oppty, name   from account where oppty in Account];      //do something to the account based on the info in the oppty } Thats, what I want to do, but it gives me a governor limit each time because I need to dataload multiple records at a time. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You need to query Account basing on set of opportunities' Ids. Compose a Set of Ids and then query Accounts where oppty in accountSetIds. After you have a list of Accounts compose a Map<Id, Account>. Put Opportunity's Id and it's corresponding Account object. Then in a for loop of objects from Trigger.xxxMap you will get an Account from composed map by it's Opportunity id.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have a question, does "List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Oppty
                                 ,name 
                           FROM account 
                           WHERE oppty IN Trigger.newMap.keySet()];" work when Account is the parent?